# c# How to pass label to an anonymous form

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to pass my Label I use in my mainForm to an anonymous form. By anonymous form I mean this form count can be infinite. I will show my code to make it clear.

This is my second form.

```
LABEL sourceObj;
public frmCounters(string text, ref LABEL _sourceObj)
{
   InitializeComponent();
   sourceObj = _sourceObj;
   this.Text = text;
   this.lblInfo.Text = text;
   this.lblTime = sourceObj;
}
```

and this is how I call it

```
AnonymForm afrm = new AnonymForm("TEST1", ref lblTEST1);
afrm.Show();
```

all I want to achieve here is update anonyform's label whenever I change the source from my main form. I have tried with and without ref keyword in constructor. I've bind the value I get in constructor to another variable I hold in anonymform. I also wanted to try send text property as reference but Visual Studio said I can't pass properties with ref keyword.

My question is how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

Add to `AnonymForm` class method like:

```
public void SetLabelText(string value)
{
    this.label.Text = value;
}
```

And call it from main form:

```
afrm.SetLabelText("TEXT");
```

Comment: I don't hold afrm. I call it in my main menu strip. Maybe thats the problem? should I hold the afrm somewhere?

Comment: @ShinoLex yes, you can hold it in some variable, or if you have many forms, hold them in array.

Comment: The amount of AnonymForm will be unknown. And not all AnonymForm's will have the same Label. Some of them may have lblTEST2 or lblTEST3 labels

Comment: Nope, holding the form object in a list did not solve it. The changes I do in mainform.lblTEST1 does not reflect to my anonymForm

Comment: @ShinoLex you shouldn't change lable on main form. Yoy must put label on child form and change text via method.

Comment: How can I do that? I'll be honest I did not understand your suggestion.